Problema "cannot find symbol" en Apache Netbeans IDE 23
A ver si alguien puede ver algo que yo no o explicarme porque el error. Lo mejor es que estoy viendo un video paso a paso de el código, hice todo igual pero en el video no pasa nada y a mi me tira error. Dejo el código de la clase que esta correcto y el "llamado" (digamos) que me tira error (de otra clase). Estoy haciendo un sistema de ventas básico.
Tablas(Java Package) - TablaCliente(Java Class)
package Tablas;

public class TablaCliente {
    
    public class Cliente {
        
        int idCliente;
        String nombreCliente;
        String apellidoCliente;
        String domicilioCliente;
        String telefonoCliente;
        String correoCliente;

        public int getIdCliente() {
            return idCliente;
        }

        public void setIdCliente(int idCliente) {
            this.idCliente = idCliente;
        }

        public String getNombreCliente() {
            return nombreCliente;
        }

        public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
            this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
        }

        public String getApellidoCliente() {
            return apellidoCliente;
        }

        public void setApellidoCliente(String apellidoCliente) {
            this.apellidoCliente = apellidoCliente;
        }

        public String getDomicilioCliente() {
            return domicilioCliente;
        }

        public void setDomicilioCliente(String domicilioCliente) {
            this.domicilioCliente = domicilioCliente;
        }

        public String getTelefonoCliente() {
            return telefonoCliente;
        }

        public void setTelefonoCliente(String telefonoCliente) {
            this.telefonoCliente = telefonoCliente;
        }

        public String getCorreoCliente() {
            return correoCliente;
        }

        public void setCorreoCliente(String correoCliente) {
            this.correoCliente = correoCliente;
        }

       
    }    
 }   

Crud (Java Package) - ClabCliente (Java Class)
package Crud;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class ClabCliente {
    
    public void MostrarCliente(JTable tablaTotalClientes) {
        
        Configuracion.CConexion objetoConexion = new Configuracion.CConexion();            
        Tablas.TablaCliente objetoCliente = new Tablas.TablaCliente();                    
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(); 
        String sql ="";            
        modelo.addColumn("id");
        modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
        modelo.addColumn("Apellido");
        modelo.addColumn("Telefono");
        modelo.addColumn("Correo");
        modelo.addColumn("Domicilio");            
        tablaTotalClientes.setModel(modelo);
        sql ="select cliente.idCliente,cliente.nombre,cliente.apellido,cliente.telefono,cliente.correo,cliente.domicilio from cliente";
        
        try {
            Statement st = objetoConexion.estableceConexion().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            
            while (rs.next()) {                    
                objetoCliente.*setIdCliente*(rs.getInt("")); 
            }                
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {  } 
        finally {  }            
    }        
}

El .setIdCliente, primero, que no me da la "autoayuda" de mostrarme los sets y, segundo, es lo que me marca como error y me aconseja crear un método... pero ya esta el setter creado... no se que estoy pifiando porque, como dije, encima estoy siguiendo un video.
Gracias.

Hola Gonzalo, en la linea objetoCliente.setIdCliente(rs.getInt("")); los "*" están de más, proba de quitarlos y comenta.

No puedes acceder a setIdCliente() definiendo TablaCliente, TablaCliente define a la clase Cliente que esta es con la que si podrías acceder al método setIdCliente().
Realiza el siguiente cambio:
 public void MostrarCliente(JTable tablaTotalClientes) {
        
        Configuracion.CConexion objetoConexion = new Configuracion.CConexion();            
        Tablas.TablaCliente objetoCliente = new Tablas.TablaCliente();  
       
        // Crear una instancia de clase Cliente
        Tablas.TablaCliente.Cliente cliente = objetoCliente.new Cliente();
                  
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(); 
        String sql ="";            
        modelo.addColumn("id");
        modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
        modelo.addColumn("Apellido");
        modelo.addColumn("Telefono");
        modelo.addColumn("Correo");
        modelo.addColumn("Domicilio");            
        tablaTotalClientes.setModel(modelo);
        sql ="select cliente.idCliente,cliente.nombre,cliente.apellido,cliente.telefono,cliente.correo,cliente.domicilio from cliente";
        
        try {
            Statement st = objetoConexion.estableceConexion().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
             public void MostrarCliente(JTable tablaTotalClientes) {
        
        Configuracion.CConexion objetoConexion = new Configuracion.CConexion();            
        Tablas.TablaCliente objetoCliente = new Tablas.TablaCliente();                    
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(); 
        String sql ="";            
        modelo.addColumn("id");
        modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
        modelo.addColumn("Apellido");
        modelo.addColumn("Telefono");
        modelo.addColumn("Correo");
        modelo.addColumn("Domicilio");            
        tablaTotalClientes.setModel(modelo);
        sql ="select cliente.idCliente,cliente.nombre,cliente.apellido,cliente.telefono,cliente.correo,cliente.domicilio from cliente";
        
        try {
            Statement st = objetoConexion.estableceConexion().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            
            while (rs.next()) {                    
                //objetoCliente.*setIdCliente*(rs.getInt("")); 
                  cliente.setIdCliente(rs.getInt(""));  
            }                
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {  } 
        finally {  }            
    }        
            while (rs.next()) {                    
                //objetoCliente.*setIdCliente*(rs.getInt("")); 
                  cliente.setIdCliente(rs.getInt(""));  
            }                
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {  } 
        finally {  }            
    }        


Gracias por la respuesta... no me podía dar cuenta... los momentos que se te bloquea el cerebro jaja. Ahora lo veo bien, muchas gracias.
